# Why is a copy constructor required here?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, ternary-operator

Consider the following code:

```
struct S
{
    S() {}
    void f();
private:
    S(const S&);
};

int main()
{
    bool some_condition;
    S my_other_S;
    (some_condition ? S() : my_other_S).f();
    return 0;
}
```

gcc fails to compile this, saying:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:6:5: error: 'S::S(const S&)' is private
test.cpp:13:29: error: within this context
```

I don't see why copy construction should be taking place on that line - the intention is to simply call `f()` on either a default-constructed `S` instance, or on `my_other_S`, i.e. it should be equivalent to:

```
if (some_condition)
    S().f();
else
    my_other_S.f();
```

What is different in the first case and why is a copy constructor required?

**EDIT**: Is there any way, then, to express "perform this operation on either a temporary on a preexisting object" in an expression context?

Comment: Isn't the if statement doing what you want? What's the advantage of doing everything in a single expression (except for obfuscation)?

Comment: @Bo the if statement requires repeating the `f()` part which may in fact be a function with many arguments, each of which may be the result of a lengthy expression... you get the idea

Comment: @Bo Moreover, in certain contexts it may not be possible to rewrite the expression as an if statement  - for example, if the expression is used as the initializer of an instance variable in an initialization list.

Comment: @Bo another example of a situation where it is necessary to stay in an expression context is if you require type deduction for a variable that stores the return value of `f()`, i.e. you can do `auto x = (some_condition ? S() : my_other_S).f();`, but you can't do `auto x; if (some_condition) x = S().f(); else x = my_other_S.f();`. And I'm sure there are many scenarios that I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of `?:` is an rvalue, a new object, if one of the arguments is an rvalue. To create this rvalue, the compiler must copy whatever the result is.

```
if (some_condition)
    S().f(); // Compiler knows that it's rvalue
else
    my_other_S.f(); // Compiler knows that it's lvalue
```

This is for the same reason that you can't do

```
struct B { private: B(const B&); };
struct C { C(B&); C(const B&); };
int main() {
    B b;
    C c(some_condition ? b : B());
}
```

I changed my example, because the old one was a bit suck. You can clearly see here there is no way to compile this expression because the compiler can't know what constructor to call. Of course, in this case, the compiler could coerce both arguments to `const B&`, but for some reason which is not very relevant, it won't.

Edit: No, there isn't, because there's no way to compile that expression, as important data about it (rvalue or lvalue) varies at run-time. The compiler tries to fix this problem for you by converting to rvalue by copy constructing, but it can't because it can't copy, so it can't compile.

Comment: @DeadMG: From my reading, the result doesn't get copied.  The other expression does.  Trying to figure out whether that's important.

Comment: @HighCommander4: It doesn't work because the compiler can't guarantee a fact about the result. Whether that fact is the type or whether that expression is rvalue or lvalue is immaterial.

Comment: If it was always copied then the following would not work as expected: `(test ? varA : varB ) = 5;` This should assign 5 to one of the two variables.

Comment: @Martin: It is not "always copied". Only class types are copied and only if the result is an *rvalue*. What do you expect from an assignment that has an rvalue on the left-hand side?

Comment: @Martin: That's because neither `varA` nor `varB` are rvalues.

Comment: @HighCommander4: I don't see any comment or answer by you anymore.

Comment: @AndreyT, @DeadMG: Obviously it is not always copied (as my example works). The point of the comment is that the answer is not explicitly clear on that point (especially if the reader is not intimately familiar with l/r/x/bla-values).

Comment: @Martin: I explicitly stated, "if one argument is an rvalue". @HighCommander4: Oh, didn't realize you were the questioner.

Comment: @DeadMG Doesn't the compiler convert an lvalue to an rvalue without copying when you do `move(x)`? Why can't it do the same here?

Comment: @DeadMG Moreover, as long as the function in question doesn't require the "this" parameter to be an rvalue reference, what's wrong with calling it on either an rvalue object or an lvalue object?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Because you didn't explicitly request it, it's extremely unsafe to start making rvalue references for fun. Also, it doesn't seem to want to produce reference results in this operator, and I'm really not quite sure why. As for `rvalue` or `lvalue`, it's easy to construct scenarios where the Standard defines different behaviour for lvalues or rvalues- `decltype` for example.

Answer (score 8):

From `[expr.cond]` (wording from draft n3242):

> Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other.  The process for determining whether an operand expression `E1` of type `T1` can be converted to match an operand expression `E2` of type `T2` is deﬁned as follows:
>
> - If `E2` is an lvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the type “lvalue reference to `T2`”, subject to the constraint that in the conversion the reference must bind directly (8.5.3) to an lvalue.
> - If `E2` is an xvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type “rvalue reference to `T2`”, subject to the constraint that the reference must bind directly.
> - If `E2` is an rvalue or if neither of the conversions above can be done and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - if `E1` and `E2` have class type, and the underlying class types are the same or one is a base class of the other:  `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if the class of `T2` is the same type as, or a base class of, the class of `T1`, and the cv-qualification of `T2` is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification than, the cv-qualification of `T1`.  If the conversion is applied, `E1` is changed to a prvalue of type `T2` by copy-initializing a temporary of type `T2` from `E1` and using that temporary as the converted operand.

This rule mentions copy-initialization, but it does not apply since both operands have the same type

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result
>   is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if
>   both are bit-fields.

This rule does not apply because `S()` is an rvalue and `my_other_S` is an lvalue.

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original
>   operands for the remainder of this section.
>   Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are per-formed on the second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type.  If the operands have class type, **the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized** from either the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand.

This rule is applied, the result is copy initialized (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 4):

This is an old known issue. See here

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#446

According to the committee decisions, in your example the `?:` operator should always return a temporary object, meaning that for `my_other_s` branch, the original `my_other_s` object will have to be copied. This is why the compiler requires the copy constructor.

This language is not yet in C++03, but many compilers implemented this approach from the very start.

Answer (score 1):

As for your updated question, if the modification of `S`'s definition is
allowed, the following work-around might help:

```
struct S
{
    ...
    S& ref() { return *this; } // additional member function
    ...
};

(some_condition ? S().ref() : my_other_S).f();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! That was precisely my intention with the original code. But it's unfortunate that I have to write and call a special member function to achieve it...